# Book for object oriented programming and approaches

Tags: oop

Can you please suggest a book for studying objected oriented approaches and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfooad/

Answer (score 1):

This is the bible of OOP:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns
```

You can find a hard copy on the Amazon but if you Google you should be able to find an html version on the net somewhere.

Comment: I would recommend the Design Patterns book as part of the "approaches" (i.e. implementations and problem solving) component of the OP's question. However, that book assumes you already have a strong understanding of OOP fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few links I found for supporting your cause. Hope these might help you -

http://oad.humansize.com/

http://www.itmweb.com/essay554.htm

http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/csharpclasses.htm

Answer (score 1):

**The** standard work on object oriented design is [Larman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062):

**[Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062)**