# C# / Object Oriented concepts book with code examples

Tags: c#, oop

I have checked many books but couldn't find any good book. I am interested in book from where I can learn OOP concepts with examples in an easy way. Book like [Java Black book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193211100X)

Comment: Not a dupe, but a good question to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836679/book-for-object-oriented-programming-and-approaches

Comment: Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design
: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008673

Comment: C# 4.0 in a Nutshell

: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two excellent books that I would recommend are:

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) by Jeffrey Richter

and

[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by "Uncle" Bob Martin

Richter's book will give you all of the details about the aspects (programming and OOP capabilities) of C#, and Martin's book will give you guidelines on writing proper code in an OO environment.  Martin's book is geared towards Java, but the concepts apply equally to C# (IMHO).

The Head First OOA&D book that Mitch mentions in comments is also excellent.  Probably the combination of all three will make you unstoppable.  :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I originally learned using *Illustrated C# 2005* a little over 3 years ago, a great book at walking you through learning c# and just oop ideas in general.

The newest Edition:
*Illustrated C# 2010* : [http://www.amazon.com/Illustrated-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/143023282X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1298342637&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023282X)

Answer (score 0):

OOP principles are not language dependent.  The only thing that changes is the syntax, and C# and Java are closely related anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple and the one I found the most straight forward for learning both OOP and C# at the same time was Deitel's How to Program Visual C# 2010. It's probably twice or three times the price of others at Amazon but I considered it money well spent.  I should mention that I'm a hobbyist programmer with no computer science background so not sure how it stacks up technically but I really enjoyed it and learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) for learning OOP with C# - I have the 2008 version of that book and it covers all the fundamentals - and once you got those down, the book offers much more as well.